# Prove that power of radical is contained in ideal

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

$A \textrm{ is a commutative ring with multiplicative identity }.\\
\alpha \textrm{ is a finitely generated  ideal of }A.\: \: \sqrt{\alpha } =\left \{ x\in A\mid  x^{m}\in \alpha \mid m\in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \right \}.\\
\textrm{Prove that }\exists n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\textrm{ such that }(\sqrt{\alpha })^{n}\subseteq \alpha $

Not getting any idea on how to proceed. Will it help if I prove that the radical is finitely generated?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You're seeking an $N$ such that the product of every collection of $N$ elements of $\sqrt{\alpha}$ is in $\alpha$.  What you are given is a finite subset $\{a_i\mid i=1\ldots k\}$of $\sqrt{\alpha}$, each of which has its own power lying in $\alpha$.

Consider this subproblem: Let $\{x_i\mid i\in 1\ldots N\}$ be a family of elements from the set $\{a_1,\ldots, a_k\}$ ($N$ may be much larger than $k$, with repeated selections.) How big must $N$ be to guarantee $\prod_{i=1}^N x_i\in \alpha$?

Now, given elements of the form $b_j=\sum a_ir_{ij}$, you know that after the expansion of the product of $N$ such sums, each term will contain (a multiple of) something of the form described in the subproblem above.   If each of those terms is in $\alpha$, then their sum will be also in $\alpha$...